# Adding custom claim to id token based on group ownership existence on Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have an (external to Azure) application to integrate with AzureAD through OIDC. The requirement is to add a custom claim to id_token with a list of groups where the user is an owner in AD.

For example if the user is in the owner of group with id = "123abc", I need to add the following custom claim to id_token.

"ownedGroups": ["123abc"]

If this is not possible is there at least option to add sth like this

"hasOwnedGroups": true

I could not find any relevant example for this in docs. Can you share an example for doing this? If this is not possible in the exactly same way, I 'd like to know the alternative solution for putting information about ownership in id token.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD does not support Groups as source for custom claims or claims mappings. You can however [create directory extensions, update them with any data you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview#directory-azure-ad-extensions) and get them in the [token as optional claims.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-directory-extension-optional-claims)